# Azure WebJob never ran. Why?

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs, webjob

Navigating to App Services in Azure, then navigating to WebJobs, I am able to add a new WebJob. I name it, upload a zip file with the necessary files, and under type, I select `triggered` instead of `continuous`. For Triggers, `scheduled` is selected.

For the CRON expression, I put `0 */5 * * * *`. Sure enough, this WebJob runs every 5 minutes. I can check my WebJob Logs to see their status and that they're returned "successful".

However, when attempting to do the same process but with a different CRON expression, the WebJob never ran.

Yesterday, I uploaded the same exact zip file as above, but with `0 0 5 * * *` as the CRON Expression (Set to run at 5AM every morning).

I checked this morning in my Microsoft Azure WebJobs Logs and under "Last Run Time", the WebJob says `Never ran`.

Why is this?

Will the WebJob not run if I'm not logged into Azure to make sure it runs? How can I guarantee this WebJob to be run?

Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Being logged in to the Azure portal has zero to do with WebJobs running.

Comment: All times are UTC. Also make sure you have `Always On` enabled for the site, otherwise the w3wp.exe process won't be around to kick off your job.

Comment: @evilSnobu Where do I go to ensure `Always On` is set?

Comment: Portal -> Your Web App -> Application Settings

Comment: @evilSnobu that was it, I had it on `OFF` I don't know if you want to post an answer, I'll mark it as correct if you do.

Comment: Done, also mentioned 6-field cron syntax since that's not something you see everyday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All times are UTC as already mentioned here by someone else. If you have something against UTC, you can alter the timezone by setting `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` application setting as detailed [**here**](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#set-the-time-zone).

Also make sure you have **Always On** enabled for the site that hosts the Webjob, otherwise the `w3wp.exe` process that is in charge of the crontab won't be around to kick off your job.

#### Azure Portal → Your Web App → Application Settings → Always On

[image: Always On]

For completness's sake, Kudu uses a **6-field** cron expression. The 1st field represents *seconds* rather than minutes (which is the first field in *classic* crontab).

More here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob

Comment: Thanks! Very insightful!